# Which versions of CustomContent are compatible with cmsms 1.5.3?

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I have cmsms 1.5.3 and I need to know which releases of the module [CustomContent](http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/project/files/31#package-27) are compatible with the version I am using.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the xml files associated with each version of [CustomContent](http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/project/files/31#package-27) you will see that version 1.5.3 of CustomContent requires cmsms 1.4.0. version 1.7.2 of CustomContent requires version 1.7.1 of cmsms.

**So you will only be able to use CustomContent version 1.5.3 with cmsms 1.5.3.**